# Android: Unable to invoke Gallery with Video

Tags: android, video, android-intent, gallery

I'm trying to invoke android gallery with videos loaded with it. This method working fine for the intent `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` but it doesn't work properly for me and returned following exceptions. Can someone hlep me out please.

```
08-09 17:12:26.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.b/a.b.SDCardVideoActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/video/media cmp=com.google.android.music/com.android.music.VideoBrowserActivity } from ProcessRecord{4052da08 878:a.b/10053} (pid=878, uid=10053) requires null




08-09 17:12:26.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(878): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/video/media cmp=com.google.android.music/com.android.music.VideoBrowserActivity } from ProcessRecord{4052da08 878:a.b/10053} (pid=878, uid=10053) requires null
```

My code goes as below

```
public class SDCardVideoActivity extends Activity {
    final int REQ_CODE_PICK_VIDEO = 1;
    String outputfilepath;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.header);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_PICK_VIDEO);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used the below code to invoke Gallery Application from my activity.

```
// contentId will have the video content id as given by Content Resolver
// In this nparticular application, contentId is retrieved from ListActivity with custom adapter

Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentId);

try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contentUri);
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**EDIT 1**

To invoke Gallery browser use the below code

```
someMethod() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
   intent.setType("video/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

To invoke Video Player use the below code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null)) {

        Log.i("---------------------", data.getData().getEncodedPath());
        mIntentFromGallery = data;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setData(data.getData());
        try
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }


    } else {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Shash

Comment: You want to launch Gallery Browser ?

Comment: yeah I want to launch native gallery browser with only videos of SD card. plz help me out