# Receive the response from second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, response

I am beginner in android, I just want to know how to get the response from the second activity to which I came from first activity.

Can any body tell me the way to do this? Is it before while calling finish() ?

I would be thankful if any one can show me the code snippet.

Comment: you want to get data from the second activity?

Comment: Yes, I have moved from audio activity to map activity, now I am coming back from map and at that time I need to send the result in the sense what exactly happened in map to Audio activity

Comment: You need to launch second activity using startActivityForResult. Code snippet is available @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995901/android-unable-to-invoke-gallery-with-video/6996131#6996131

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call the second activity using the `startActivityForResult` method. In your second activity, when it is finished, you can execute the `setResult` method where basically you put the result information. Then, on your first activity, you override the `onActivityResult` method.

Answer (score 9):

Call second activity like this

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);

 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 37);
```

Finish SecondActivity like this

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Override `onActivityResult` in FirstActivity like this

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 37) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {                


            }
        }


   }
```