# How to return a value from dialog in separate class

Tags: java, android, class, android-alertdialog

I want to create a function  that shows a dialog with 2 buttons on screen and return 1 if user pressed OK and 0 if user pressed Cancel.

```
public class CDlg {

static int ShowConfirm(String caption, String msg, Context context) {
    int rez;
    AlertDialog.Builder delAllDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    delAllDialog.setTitle(caption);

    TextView dialogTxt_id = new TextView(context);
    LayoutParams dialogTxt_idLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialogTxt_id.setLayoutParams(dialogTxt_idLayoutParams);
    dialogTxt_id.setText(msg);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(dialogTxt_id);
    delAllDialog.setView(layout);

    delAllDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            rez = 1;
        }
    });

    delAllDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            rez = 0;
        }
    });

    delAllDialog.show();
    return rez;
}
```

}

I am now shure that I am doing right because I do not know how to pass a result from unner class to outer one. There is a error message

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable rez inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

So as a result I want to use that function something like this:

```
if (CDlg.ShowConfirm("User confirmation","Delete?",this)==1){
        ...
}
```

Comment: You must call the second activity using the startActivityForResult method. In your second activity, when it is finished, you can execute the setResult method where basically you put the result information. Then, on your first activity, you override the onActivityResult method. (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020583/receive-the-response-from-second-activity)

Comment: yes, this is an option, I know how to do this, but I wanted to explore something like that to avoide code coping )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this like that. `ShowConfirm` can only show the dialog. When the user clicks either the OK or Cancel button, only then you can execute what you want:

```
public class CDlg {
    void ShowConfirm(String caption, String msg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder delAllDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        delAllDialog.setTitle(caption);

        TextView dialogTxt_id = new TextView(this);
        LayoutParams dialogTxt_idLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogTxt_id.setLayoutParams(dialogTxt_idLayoutParams);
        dialogTxt_id.setText(msg);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(dialogTxt_id);
        delAllDialog.setView(layout);

        delAllDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                handleButtonClick(1);
            }
        });

        delAllDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                handleButtonClick(2);
            }
        });

        delAllDialog.show();
    }

    void handleButtonClick(int rez) {
        switch(rez) {
            case 1: ..... break;
            case 2: ..... break;
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

The `if (CDlg.ShowConfirm("User confirmation","Delete?",this)==1)` statement is useless in Android here, since the ShowConfirm will not wait until the user presses a button.

Instead just call `ShowConfirm("User confirmation","Delete?");` an implement the appropriate code in the `onClick`s.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so for example, if a have many user-menu options like "delete something-1", "delete something-2" etc. I should write this long code for every menu item?

Comment: Yes. But if that code is very similar for all(most) menu items, then you should refactor it to make use of that shared code (see handleButotnClick in answer).

Comment: So that was my try to do this. Dialogs is the same, may be a caption will differ.

Comment: Thank you, I should get used to such a code (just like jumping). I just think it is a litte messy for me right now, but I understand it and will get used to.  Please tell me why ShowConfirm will not wait until user press the button? For me to understand such things in another situations.

Comment: The final call the delAllDialog.show() will just show the dialog and return immediately. The dialog will then consume the events related to user input and such, enabling it to call the onClickListener callbacks. Android is event-driven programming, where code on the main UI thread never (should) take long (<20 millisecs if possible).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code in the spirit of Android, you should actually use startActivityForResult. Look at the linked answer for details how it should work. ([here is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29))

Comment: thank you, I know how to do this, I just thought that another way exists.. :(

Comment: Well, if I can be honest: it sounds like you're trying to change Android's behavior to the one you're used to (looks like you're used to C#/WPF?). And that won't help you in the long run. If you prefer to code that way, wouldn't Mono for Android suit you better?

Comment: You read my mind. Thank you for advice, I will get used to this soon. there are so many things in a World Human can get used to))

Answer (score 0):

Define a static variable in the class you want, for example I will define in MyAuxiliaryClass.java:

```
public static USER_DECISION = -1;
```

Whenever you choose an option, then you do the following:

```
if (//Desicion == OK) {
MyAuxiliaryClass.USER_DECISION = 1;
} else (//Decision == NOT OK){
MyAuxiliaryClass.USER_DECISION = 2;
}
```

Since you are changing this static variable, then you can get the value 1 or 2 in another class. Hope it helps. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Make `rez` an attribute instead of a local variable. As your method is `static`, the attribute should be too. This means moving the definition outside the method.

public class CDlg {

```
   static int rez;

   static int ShowConfirm(String caption, String msg, Context context) {
   ...
```

In the inner classes, you need to refer to the CDlg class

```
   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        CDlg.rez = 1;
   }
```

As a side note, it is strange that you use an `static` method for this. One of the mistakes of the people new to Java/OOP is to abuse `static` code, that feels more like `C` was. Maybe you want to reconsider your code.

Comment: The OP needs to redesign the code. The ShowConfirm call will not wait until the user presses one of the button. It returns immediately.

Comment: so the goal was to ecape copying code with confirm dialog for many menu options :(